# Rails active storage, Unpermitted parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-activestorage

I am using Rails API and Vue for front-end. I am trying to let users upload their avatar using Active Storage. However, Rails complains that the avatar parameter is not allowed.

On the front-end I have a simple input

```
<input id="avatar" type="file" @change="onImageChange" />
```

Which, when changed triggers

```
onImageChange(event) {
  this.avatar = event.target.files[0];
}
```

Then, on submit

```
submit() {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("avatar", this.avatar);
      this.axios
        .put("/api/signup", {
          ...
          user: {
            ...
            avatar: formData
          }
        })
```

We receive the request in the RegistrationsController#update. We include the avatar in the white list

```
  def account_update_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:avatar, ...)
  end
```

And the model user has_one_attached :avatar.

However, on submit, I get

> Parameters:
>   {"headers"=>{...},
>   "user"=>{..., "avatar"=>{}}}
>
> Unpermitted parameter: :avatar

I have also tried to white list it using .permit!(:avatar) and got the same result. Any idea what might be the problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I arrived here because I was getting the unpermitted parameter message with ActiveStorage when using multiple attachments.

#### Generic example

To ensure you permit multiple ActiveStorage attachments, change this

```rb
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content, :files)
end
```

to this

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content, files: [])
end
```

Further info in [here](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#has-many-attached)

Answer (score 0):

I see avatar as json and not an temp file object. Suppose that json is as follows:
Parameters: {"headers"=>{...}, "user"=>{..., "avatar"=>{ "name" => "test.png", "file": <# Temp File Obj>}}}

Then we will use statement

```
params.require(:user).permit(..., avatar: [:name, :file])
```